# Manipulate individual numbers inside of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, double

Working on some homework and I want to make my code more precise, I have a set of values inside of an array that I need to convert into a different set of numbers while still being inside the array. Since this is for my homework I don't want to actually post what I am working on, so I will post an example, wouldn't want anyone doing my work for me!

```
public class Example{
    public Example(){
        double rainfall [] = {1.07, 3.25, 4.51, 2.32, 8.28}; //in Inches
        System.out.print("Enter i for Inches or c for Centimeters ");
        String scale = in.next();

        if(scale.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){

            for (double i : rainfall){
                rainSum += i;
            }//End for


        // Here is where I am lost on what to do in my current program I have it 
        // to where it adds up all the numbers as inches and then converts them into
        // centimeters, however I need to display every number in centimeters, so I
        // cannot do it that way.
        }//End if
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what all you want?

Sum of the elements of the rainfall array in cms?
Apart from this do you need anything else?

Comment: I need to convert the rainfall in inches to rainfall in centimeters while preserving the original array.

Comment: Do you just want to display the numbers in centimeters (eg to standard output), or do you want to make a new array with those numbers?

Comment: I want to display the numbers in centimeters, not make a new array. I have the original array with the numbers in inches and then the if statement needs to convert those numbers into centimeters and then display them. I need to keep the original array because the user (in my program not the example) can select for the output to be displayed in inches rather than centimeters.

Comment: Also, to clarify I need to display each number individually as well as the total in centimeters. While the total part is easy, I am unsure of how to do it for the individuals.

Comment: @user3053524 : see my answer. If that aides you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I suppose you have stats of rainfall of 5 days. They are provided in Inches and you need to output 2 things(Based on if the user selects 'C') :

(1). Total rainfall in cms.

(2). Daily rainfall stats in cms.

(3). You need to do this while preserving the original array in Inches.

So I would suggest you following code :

(1).
    You are pretty correct on thinking in doing this. Add all the elements and multiply them by 2.54
    to get its equivalent in cms.
(2).
    call a method display as following :

```
void display(double[] a) // This would print individual rainfall stats in cms. 
{
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
  System.out.println(a[i]*2.54);//Modify formatting as per your requirements
 }
}
```

(3).
    These remain as is.

**Method-2 :**
If the expectancy of program getting input as 'C' is more, then create another array
that actually converts the initial inches array to cms array.
So, now you have two arrays :

rainfallInches[]    & rainfallCms[]

You can use them as follows :

```
for(int i=0;i<rainfallInches.length;i++)
{
 rainfallCms[i] = rainfallInches[i]*2.54; 
}// This creates new cms array
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In regards to your first method, I fully understand everything other than the void display and why the "a" is there, is there another way of doing this same task in Java? Other than that I appreciate your help a lot, many thanks!

Comment: No there is no other way. Programming revolves around the same concept. 'a' here is actually the parameter that is being passed from our program(when this function is called), 'a' is the element/object on which the method performs functions.

Comment: Also, I did that wrong. The datatype of the parameter should had been double[]. You can call the show method in your code as 'display(rainfall);'.

Comment: I see, that helps I think I know how to implement this into my code and make it work. Thanks a lot for your help! I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation I guess because I just registered, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding up all of the numbers and converting that sum (inches) into centimeters by multiplying by 2.54.  The values in your array are still in inches, so to print all of them out in centimeters, simply iterate through the array and print the value multiplied by 2.54.  Alternatively, if you need the transformed values and the original, simply copy the array, but multiplying each entry by 2.54.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is what I need to do, however I don't know how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve the original values you will need to create a new array and copy the converted values to the corresponding positions in the new array.

If you don't need to preserve the original values use array element assignment, for instance:

```
 private static final double CENTIMETERS_PER_INCH = 2.54d;
 ...
 a[1] = a[i] * CENTIMETERS_PER_INCH;
```

in a loop to calculate the converted values. The constant definition would appear at the class level, not in the loop.

Comment: If I were to create a new array the result in my code would make it look rather sloppy and I do not want that. I just want to preserve the original array as it is in inches, and convert those numbers inside the array to centimeters while inside of an if statement.

Comment: If you just want to print the converted values, just use a temporary variable inside the loop, or just print the expression directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example{

public interface Constants{
    /**
     * Centimer to inch
     */
    static final double CENTIMETER_TO_INCH = 0.393701;

    /**
     * Centimer to inch
     */
    static final double INCH_TO_CENTIMETER = 2.54;
}

public double[] convertToCentimeter(double[] rainfallInInches){
    int length = rainfallInInches.length;
    double[] rainfallInCentimeters = new double[length];
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
        rainfallInCentimeters[i] = rainfallInInches[i] * Constants.INCH_TO_CENTIMETER;
    }

    return rainfallInCentimeters;
}

public double[] convertToInches(double[] rainfallInCentimeter){
    int length = rainfallInCentimeter.length;
    double[] rainfallInInches = new double[length];
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
        rainfallInInches[i] = rainfallInCentimeter[i] * Constants.CENTIMETER_TO_INCH;
    }

    return rainfallInInches;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    double rainfall [] = {1.07, 3.25, 4.51, 2.32, 8.28}; //in Inches

    // Test convert to centimeter
    Example example = new Example();
    double[] convertedArray = example.convertToCentimeter(rainfall);

    System.out.print("{");
    for(int i = 0; i < convertedArray.length; i++){
        System.out.print(convertedArray[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("}");
} // end main

}
```